# Passing variable from AR view to .sheet freezes the app or doesn't work

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit

In RealityKit I am creating video planes - plane mesh with VideoMaterial and I'm trying to open a `.sheet` that shows the name of the entity when user taps on the video plane.

I was able to make the touch work and also get the correct entity name, but when the sheet is shown it's as if the variable that holds the entity name was empty.

In the code below (see `func updateUIView` for the most relevant part) when I print the tappedEntityName it's filled correctly.

```
struct ARExperience: UIViewRepresentable {
    var arView = ARView(frame: .zero) 
    
    @Binding var point: CGPoint
    @Binding var stateSwitcher: Bool 
    @Binding var tappedEntityName: String?
    @Binding var isSheetShowing: Bool
    
    //...
    
    init(point: Binding<CGPoint>, stateSwitcher: Binding<Bool>, tappedEntityName: Binding<String?>, isSheetShowing: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._point = point
        self._stateSwitcher = stateSwitcher
        self._tappedEntityName = tappedEntityName
        self._isSheetShowing = isSheetShowing
        //...
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSessionDelegate {
        var parent: ARExperience
        init(parent: ARExperience) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        func createVideoPlane(_ target: ARReferenceImage) -> ModelEntity {
            var videoPlane = ModelEntity()
            var targetName: String = ""
            if let name = target.name,
                //...
                    videoPlane.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
                    videoPlane.name = targetName
                    //...
                    }
                } else {
                    //...
                }
            }
            return videoPlane
        }
        //...
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        let ray = uiView.ray(through: point)
        let castHits = uiView.scene.raycast(origin: ray?.origin ?? [0,0,0],
                                       direction: ray?.direction ?? [0,0,0])
        guard let castHit: CollisionCastHit = castHits.first else {
            print("Raycast didn't hit anything")
            return
        }
        if !stateSwitcher || stateSwitcher {
            print("Successfully tapped on \(castHit.entity.name)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tappedEntityName = castHit.entity.name
                print("Tapped Entity Name: \(tappedEntityName)")
                self.isSheetShowing = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My main view - here I get the problem that I get print 'Unknown entity tapped' as if the value of the binding variable didn't get through.

```
struct ARExperienceView: View {
    @StateObject var tappedEntityName = tappedEntityName()
    
    @State var point = CGPoint.zero
    @State var stateSwitcher = true
    
    @State var isSheetShowing: Bool = false
     
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                ARExperience(point: $point, stateSwitcher: $stateSwitcher, tappedEntityName: $tappedEntityName, isSheetShowing: $isSheetShowing)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if !isSheetShowing {
                            point = CGPoint(x: Int($0.x), y: Int($0.y))
                            print("Tapped \(point.x)")
                            stateSwitcher.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetShowing, content: {
                        VStack {
                            if let entityName = tappedEntityName {
                                Text("You tapped on: \(tappedEntityName)")
                            } else {
                                Text("Unknown entity tapped")
                            }
                        }
                    })
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Close", action: {
                        })
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried is to change `@Binding var tappedEntityName` to:

```
class TappedEntity: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String? = nil
}
```

and then in the main view have it as `@StateObject var tappedEntity = TappedEntity()`. This works - it shows the name of the entity in the .sheet, but the app seems to become unresponsive in this case. I am unable to close the sheet - by dragging down or even by adding a Dismiss button.

In this case also the console shows (at the time of .sheet showing):

```
2023-06-04 11:57:34.528404+0200 MyARApp[14653:1950473] [CAMetalLayer nextDrawable] returning nil because allocation failed.
```

Comment: If you use the setup recommended in your previous question this will be solved

Comment: You should also use `.sheet(item:)`